# How to click on Hidden link through Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click on a hidden link through Selenium Webdriver.

I am using the below code:

```
WebElement dwnld = driver.findElement((By.xpath("////form[@id='aspnetForm']/div[6]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/a")));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action hoverAction = builder.click(dwnld).build();
hoverAction.perform();
```

Comment: What happens? What errors? With what exception? As a general rule in Selenium, if a user cannot click on it, then *neither* can Selenium. You must think from a user perspective - how does a user make that link visible? If they cannot, then you have bigger problems.

Comment: Exception:-
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds

Comment: Looking at xpath, I'm confused how you were able to find that element. Because you've used four '/' instead of two '/'. Is the element still searched?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show the link before clicking on it for some reason you can use javascript to click on it (see JavaScriptExecutor).

Comment: General behavior:-If we drag mouse over that place then link will be shown.. and i want to show the link and then want to click on it.

Comment: If I correctly understand what you need you should hover visible element that contains hidden link and reacts on the hover event. After that link becomes visible and you will get a possibility to click on  it. Hope this help

Answer (score -1):

```
String Block1 = driver.findElement(By.id("element ID"));

JavascriptExecutor js1=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;

js1.executeScript("$("+Block1+").css({'display':'block'});");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!